# How to add datepicker popup to input field with YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format in angular2

Tags: angular

How to add datepicker popup to input field with YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format in angular.

I added like below in .html file but not effecting.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="date2" ngui-datetime-picker
     date-format="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
     hour="23"
     minute='59'
     close-on-select="false"/>
```

And i installed and imported ngui-datetime-picker in app.module.ts file.

```
import { NguiDatetimePickerModule } from '@ngui/datetime-picker';

@NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, NguiDatetimePickerModule],
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find 
[working sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/3NrykMPnf1p0nxsJCIka?p=preview%60%60) as per your need I've created plnkr.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="date2" ngui-datetime-picker    date-format="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"    hour="23"    minute='59'    close-on-select="false"  />
```

Please verify that you have to import

```
import { NguiDatetimePickerModule, DateTime } from '@ngui/datetime-picker';
```

and export Datetime

```
 export 
    {  
    DateTime
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for response..i tried the same example but DateTime giving error like "@ngui/datetime-picker/dist/index" has no exported member DateTime. So please suggest me what i need to do for this.

Comment: Now i am getting datepicker but selection of date and times are not working.. Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Can you please share plnkr which rectifies your issue